# trait with only case objects custom implementation in spray json

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

Given I have the following declaration:

```
sealed trait Color
case object DColor extends Color
case object CColor extends Color
case object VColor extends Color
```

And then I use them In a case class like so:

```
case class CustomColor(c: Color)
CustomColor(VColor)
```

Now I want this to produce a JSON like so:

```
{c:"v_color"}
```

Comment: is your question about how to convert this case class to JSON or how to use that serializer in Spray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should define a custom format:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object ColorJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Color] {
               def write(c: Color) = c match {
                  case VColor => JsString("v_color")
                  case _ => JsString("foo")
               }

               def read(value: JsValue) = ???
    }

    implicit val customColorFormat = jsonFormat1(CustomColor.apply)
}
```

Then

```
alex-alex@ import MyJsonProtocol._
alex-alex@ CustomColor(VColor).toJson
res18: JsValue = {"c":"v_color"}
```